# Blazor Wasm Hosted Error Sorry, there's nothing at this address

Tags: c#, blazor-webassembly

I am getting the following error when trying to call the API Method in my server side controller

What am I doing wrong here.

Additionally i am also getting "Sorry nothing at this address when calling /swagger"

index.razor

```
 var httpclient = new HttpClient();
            httpclient.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:7191/");
            var result =  httpclient.GetStringAsync($"api/Account/LoginUser?userName={userName}&Email={Email}");
```

My Controller

```
using BlazorChatApp.Shared;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.Security.Claims;

namespace BlazorChatApp.Server.Controllers
{

   
    [Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class AccountController : ControllerBase
    {

      
        [HttpGet]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public async Task<ActionResult> LoginUser(string userName, string Email)
        {
          
          
            var claims = new List<Claim>
            {
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, userName),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, Email),
                new Claim("UserDefined", "whatever"),
            };

           
            var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

            var claimsPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity);

           // await HttpContext.SignInAsync(claimsPrincipal);
           // await HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, claimsPrincipal, new AuthenticationProperties { IsPersistent = true });

            await HttpContext.SignInAsync(
            JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
            claimsPrincipal,
            new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationProperties
            {
                ExpiresUtc = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(20),
                IsPersistent = true,
                AllowRefresh = true,
                IssuedUtc = DateTimeOffset.Now
            });

            return Ok(new User());

        }
    }
}
```

server side program.cs

```
using BlazorChatApp.Server;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.ResponseCompression;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddSignalR();
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    // Identity made Cookie authentication the default.
    // However, we want JWT Bearer Auth to be the default.
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
}).AddJwtBearer(options =>
{
    // Configure the Authority to the expected value for
    // the authentication provider. This ensures the token
    // is appropriately validated.
    options.Authority = "https://testApp:888"; // TODO: Update URL

    // We have to hook the OnMessageReceived event in order to
    // allow the JWT authentication handler to read the access
    // token from the query string when a WebSocket or 
    // Server-Sent Events request comes in.

    // Sending the access token in the query string is required due to
    // a limitation in Browser APIs. We restrict it to only calls to the
    // SignalR hub in this code.
    // See https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core/signalr/security#access-token-logging
    // for more information about security considerations when using
    // the query string to transmit the access token.
    options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
    {
        OnMessageReceived = context =>
        {
            var accessToken = context.Request.Query["access_token"];

            // If the request is for our hub...
            var path = context.HttpContext.Request.Path;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(accessToken) &&
                (path.StartsWithSegments("/chathub")))
            {
                // Read the token out of the query string
                context.Token = accessToken;
            }
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    };
});



builder.Services.AddResponseCompression(opts =>
{
    opts.MimeTypes = ResponseCompressionDefaults.MimeTypes.Concat(
        new[] { "application/octet-stream" });
});


builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();

app.UseResponseCompression();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseWebAssemblyDebugging();
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "SwaggerTest"));
    //app.UseSwaggerUI();
    //app.UseSwaggerUI(options =>
    //{
    //    options.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "v1");
    //    options.RoutePrefix = string.Empty;
    //});
}
else
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseBlazorFrameworkFiles();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();


app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapRazorPages();
    endpoints.MapControllers();
    endpoints.MapHub<ChatHub>("/chathub");
    endpoints.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");
});



app.Run();
```

Answer (score 6):

For my case, it was due to me deleting Index.razor page and then re-adding it back.

The above actions caused these lines to get added in .csproj file:

```
<ItemGroup><Content Remove="Pages\Index.razor" />
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup><None Include="Pages\Index.razor" />
</ItemGroup>
```

After removing the above lines from csproj file manually, everything works again.

Comment: Yep, this fixed it for me. 
Also found that same suggestion from Jens Rabe on Github.

Answer (score 1):

If you're debugging your solution from Visual Studio and you accidentally set the WASM client project as the start-up project, you'll get "Sorry, there's nothing at this address" for what you think are server-side requests. This is because the server won't be started and Blazor will get all requests.